# iOS open in... menu

Tags: ios, document

I'm working on some map app. In my app I produce json file which I'm sharing by email. In next step I'd like to be able to open this file in my app again. I followed steps described  in this article : https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1587/_index.html but I don't see my app in open in... menu. This is what my config looks like [image: Document types] [image: exported UTIs]

What should be wrong with that config?